# BackgroundWorker progressBar - Problem implementing ReportProgress when loop occurs in another class

Tags: c#

Hi
I am trying to integrate a background worker with a progress bar but cannot get it right.

I am processing some files and all the processing is done in an external class.

My difficulty is that the looping is inside this class,where usually  I do the talking to the backgroundworker.

The good thing is that when processing a file,an event is fired whenever each file has completed processing.

This is my code any suggestions how could this be achieved

```
    BackgroundWorker _bw = new BackgroundWorker

    private void RunLongProcess()
    {   
        _bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        _bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;        
        _bw.DoWork += DoWork;
        _bw.ProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;
        _bw.RunWorkerCompleted += RunWorkerCompleted;

        _bw.RunWorkerAsync();//start the process

        if (_bw.IsBusy)
           _bw.CancelAsync();
    }

     static void DoWork (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
      {      

        var files=GetFiles();
        int fileCount=files.Count;

        //usually I do a loop here but all the processing is done inside this class so

        var fileProcessor=new FileProcesser();
        fileProcessor.ProcessFiles(files);          

      }
    private void OnFileProcessCompleted(object sender, FileEventArgs e)
    {
        //Event Fired when a file has been processed 
        //How do I update progressBar.Problem cross threading here.

                        //What do I do here?????
        _bw.ReportProgress(e.FileProcessedCount, e);
    }

    ProgressChanged (object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
          // Update the UI
        labelProgress.Text = e.UserState;
        progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }


    private void RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
           // Console.WriteLine("You canceled!");
        else if (e.Error != null)
            //Console.WriteLine("Worker exception: " + e.Error.ToString());
        else
           // Console.WriteLine("Complete: " + e.Result);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>`_bw.ReportProgress(e.FileProcessedCount, e);` should not go in `OnFileProcessCompleted`.  This event is fired when `DoWork` completes.  You should place that in `DoWork` to update the progress bar.  So it would look something like this:</s>

```
private void DoWork (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{      
   BackgroundWorker bg = sender as BackgroundWorker;

   var files = GetFiles();
   int fileCount = files.Count;

   var fileProcessor = new FileProcesser();
   for(int i = 0; i < fileCount; i++)
   {
      fileProcessor.ProcessFile(files[i]);
      bg.ReportProgress( (uint)((i / (double)fileCount) * 100));
   } 
}
```

I would pass in the BackgroundWorker to the FileProcessor like this:

```
private void DoWork (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker bg = sender as BackgroundWorker;      
    var files = GetFiles();
    int fileCount = files.Count;
    var fileProcessor=new FileProcesser(bg);
    fileProcessor.ProcessFiles(files);          
}
```

In the FileProcesser, it would look something like this:

```
private BackgroundWorker _bg;
public FileProcessor(BackgroundWorker bg)
{
   _bg = bg;
}

public void ProcessFiles(Files files)
{
    // Process files
    // ...
    // Report Progress
    _bg.ReportProgress(e.FileProcessedCount, e);
}
```

Comment: Not true, `RunWorkerCompleted` is what is fired when `DoWork` completes. It looks like `OnFileProcessCompleted` is an event raised by `fileProcessor`

Comment: @Aphex - Yeah looks you are right.  In that case, the OP will need to pass in the BackgroundWorker bg to the FileProcessor and call ReportProgress from there.  No need to call a completed event.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, one solution is to make a derived class from `BackgroundWorker`, make it subscribe to the event, and have it send the progress event to the UI thread in the event handler.